# I keep getting this [<__main__.Developer object at 0x0000025051433DF0>] . Why isn't it printing out the attribute employees?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
class Employee:

    raise_amt = 1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
        self.pay = pay

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amt)


class Developer(Employee):
    raise_amt = 1.10

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang


class Manager(Employee):

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, employees=None):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        if employees is None:
            self.employees = []
        else:
            self.employees = employees

    def add_emp(self, emp):
        if emp not in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(emp)

    def remove_emp(self, emp):
        if emp in self.employees:
            self.employees.remove(emp)

    def print_emps(self):
        for emp in self.employees:
            print('-->', emp.fullname())


dev_1 = Developer('Corey', 'Schafer', 50000, 'Python')
dev_2 = Developer('Test', 'Employee', 60000, 'Java')

mgr_1 = Manager('Sue', 'Smith', 90000, [dev_1])


mgr_1.add_emp(dev_2)
mgr_1.remove_emp(dev_2)

print(mgr_1.employees)
```

Comment: I'm guessing `Developer` is a class you defined. Unless that class defins a `__repr__` or `__str__` method, simply printing an instance will just give you the output you show (python can't guess what's the "right" way to print an object, so it gives you only what module it was defined int and the memory address). Either define one of tose two methods (preferred way, IMO), or print attribute by attribute.

Comment: actually, it seems they have print an attribute only `print(mgr_1.employees)` where `employees` is an attribute of type `list`

Answer (score 1):

It is printing exactly what is expected.
If you want to have it in somewhat more readable way, just modify `Employee` class like this:

```py
class Employee:
    raise_amt = 1.04

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.email = first + '.' + last + '@email.com'
        self.pay = pay

    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first, self.last)

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * self.raise_amt)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return self.fullname()
```